# Can an AWS lambda handler be created in Kotlin/Java without implementing RequestHandler?

Tags: java, kotlin, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

TLDR: In CDK, a the lambda handler is a method reference, so for Java/Kotlin is it required that you implement the RequestHandler class?

The typical approach for defining a lambda in Java/Kotlin is to extend the request handler class and override the handleRequest function. However, when you have many similar functions in Java, this results in many similar files/class definitions.

The recommended definition looks like this:

```java
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Event, String>{

  @Override
  public String handleRequest(Event event, Context context)
  {
      ...
  }
}
```

And the simplest I can come up with in Kotlin is naturally not a significant improvement. It looks like this:

```kotlin
class Handler : RequestHandler<Event, String> {
    override fun handleRequest(request: Event, context: Context) : String {
       ...
    }
}
```

In CDK, a the lambda handler is a method reference, so is the "RequestHandler" implementation necessary? This is really the key question, putting this at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to implement the `RequestHandler` interface. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html), you just need to tell AWS which function to invoke if your class doesn't implement `RequestHandler` interface:

```
example.Handler::handleRequest
```

There's nothing special about defining such a function in a CDK application:

```java
Function handlerFunction = Function.Builder.create(this, "ExampleHandlerFunction")
        .functionName("example-handler-function")
        .handler("example.Handler::handleRequest")
        .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_11)
        .code(Code.fromAsset("path/to/the/jar"))
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java the simplest Lambda handler looks like:

```
public class SampleHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream,
                              OutputStream outputStream,
                              Context context) throws IOException {
        context.getLogger().log("in the Lambda handler");
    }
}
```

within the `handleRequest` method you will have to read from the `inputStream`.  One example could be:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

YourObject yourObject = mapper.readValue(inputStream, YourObject.class);
```

Now you have the object that Lambda would normally deserialize for you.  To "return" something you just need to write to the `outputStream`:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
writer.write("{\"result\":\"everything is awesome\"}");

writer.close();
```

Of course you could also use something like `mapper.writeValue(outputStream, yourResultObject)` to not do the JSON serialization yourself.